# CSS transition Property not working with Transform

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

I have been trying to get some transition effect on my div boxes. But it doesent Work

```
.box{
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: blueviolet;
            margin: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            transform: translateX(200%);
             transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        }



.box.show{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

I am Aware that i am not using a button to add a class. i am just adding it manually and saving. But it dosent seem to work.
here's the full code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/o7vkx6q2/3/)

Comment: This seems to be working fine. You can check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kec5zsyb/). Kindly share whole code or brief your scenario better.

Comment: @ManojMohan
Here's the full Code
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/o7vkx6q2/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the show class on the box right off the bat will not show any animation. If you use `setInterval` (For demonstration purposes), you will see that the animation works.

```js
//Toggle the class every second
setInterval(function(){ 
    document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('show');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.box{
  padding: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateX(10%);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box.show{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!-- will animate since the show class is added after the initial render -->
<div id="box" class="box">I'm a box with show class added after initial render </div>

<!-- Will not animate, the show class will determine it's initial transform -->
<div class="box show">I'm a box with show already added </div>
```

Comment: I am aware of that , I am just adding it manually to check that if its working or not.
But it seems its not working . Here's the full code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/o7vkx6q2/3/)

Comment: It's working fine. You can see it in action if you remove the overflow: hidden on the body. https://jsfiddle.net/a9yp8kvd/

Comment: You actually need to add the class after the page is rendered or you won't see a transition. Having `show` already on the element  is the problem.

Comment: oh yeah , its working after adding a button. My bad
Thanx for answering

Comment: Clarified the answer to help anyone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

Transition is an animation.
You could take a look at it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

You need to "call" it with an action

```
box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Or you can add it in JavaScript using an event

Answer (score 0):

You have to use transition with some active like :hover,:focus try playing around with:

```
.box:hover{
transform: translateX(0);}
```